# Spin structures and bitangents

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gt.geometric-topology

I came across an interesting remark in Atiyah's classic paper, [Riemann surfaces and spin structures](http://dx.doi.org/10.24033/asens.1205). He computes that there are 28 spin structures on a genus 3 surface with Arf invariant 1, and then writes, “these correspond to the famous 28 bitangents of a plane quartic”.

Can anyone explain the statement about the bitangents?

Comment: As you can find in Atiyah's paper, and also in Mumford's paper in the same volume of the Annales of ENS, spin structures on a (compact) Riemann surface $X$ corespond to theta-characteristics, that is, line bundles $L$ such that $L^2\cong K_X$; and the corresponding Arf invariant is $h^0(L)\ \mathrm{(mod.\ 2)}$. If the Arf invariant is 1, we have $L=\mathcal{O}_X(D)$ for some effective divisor $D$. Now if $X$ is non hyperelliptic of genus 3, it is isomorphic to a plane quartic, and the canonical system $|K_X|$ is cut out by lines; thus $2D$ must be cut out by a bitangent line.

Comment: By adjunction, a smooth quartic curve $X$ in $\mathbb{CP}^2$ is a genus $3$ compact Riemann surface embedded by the canonical linear system, i.e., $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{CP}^2}(1)|_X \cong \omega_X$.  For each pair of points $p,q\in X$, the square of $\mathcal{O}_X(\underline{p}+\underline{q})$ equals $\omega_X$ if and only if there exists a line $L\subset \mathbb{CP}^2$ whose intersection with $X$ equals $2\underline{p}+2\underline{q}$, i.e., $L$ is bitangent to $X$ at $p$ and $q$.  Thus the odd theta characteristics correspond to bitangent lines.

Comment: There's also a blog post on this by Akhil Mathew here: https://amathew.wordpress.com/2013/06/23/theta-characteristics-and-framings/

Comment: Thanks--those are very helpful. To abx and Jason Starr: I'd be happy to accept either of your comments if you want to make it into an answer.